# Assign a quality profile to a project via Sonarqube REST api

Tags: api, rest, sonarqube

I found how to assign a quality gate to a project, but I couldn't find the api endpoint to set a quality profile for a project.

How do I set a quality profile for a certain project via REST api?

I [checked the documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Web+Service+API) @ sonar/api_documentation and I read the source code, with no luck..

Best regards
Philipp

Answer (score 1):

There is no dedicated API yet (as of 5.1) but it will come soon (expected in 5.2).

As a workaround, you can use the `api/properties` Web Service to set property `sonar.profile.<your language>` on a given project, e.g:

```
curl -X POST -u 'admin:admin' \
     -d 'resource=com.mycompany:myproject' \
     -d 'id=sonar.profile.java' \
     -d 'value=My Quality Profile' \
     'http://mysonarqubeinstance.tld/api/properties'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit new to this but I'm using the API with Postman and this should get it done:

```
curl -X POST -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" 
-H "Postman-Token: 0d2ea3a7-785e-89c7-e1cd-428bc3b21a9a" 
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW" 
-F "projectKey=daBestProjectKey" 
-F "profileName=daBestProfileName" 
"http://localhost:9000/api/qualityprofiles/add_project"
```

Based on documentation from [nemo.sonarqube.org](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation/api/qualityprofiles)